# Make body content take 100% width of the browser

Tags: html, css

I am creating a webpage using CSS and HTML and I am trying to make it responsive. The problem is that when I use the dev tools to inspect the page it seems that the content of the page does not take 100% of the window for some reason and I can't find out why. Why doesn't my content stretch to 100%? Here is a picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFWpH.jpg

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 8%;
}

.nav-h1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-top: 27px;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-image: url(/assets/images/logo.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content-inside {
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #01568a !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.a-container {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 27px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.alignleft {
  margin-left: 8%;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #000000;
}

.alignright {
  margin-right: 8%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logo-section {
  margin-top: 1.3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.logo-img {
  padding: 6px;
}

.first-section {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("/assets/images/first-logo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.first-section-p {
  width: 400px;
  height: 314px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  color: #01568a;
}

.small-button {
  width: 331px;
  height: 92px;
  background-color: #e7af17;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}

.second-section-text {
  color: #e8e8e8;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 120px;
  line-height: 0.7;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

.second-section {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.third-section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.third-section-right-part {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.third-section-right-part-img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.third-section-left-part {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 7%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.forth-section {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.info-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-right: 7%;
  width: 36%;
  background-color: #e7af17;
}

.info-box-content {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 330px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  color: #01568a;
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.info-box-content-h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info-box-content-p {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.message {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 13%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

.second-section-right-part {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.second-section-right-part-h3 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #01568a;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.second-section-right-part-p {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.plus {
  color: orange;
}

.second-section-paragraphs {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.second-se {
  color: #01568a;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.third-section-text {
  font-size: 140px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 120px;
  line-height: 0.7;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.third-section-paragraphs {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -5%;
  margin-top: -10;
}

.forth-section-p {
  font-size: 140px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 120px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

.forth-section-paragraphs {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.third-section-paragraphs {
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: -8%;
}

.third-section-paragraphs {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -5%;
  margin-top: -10;
}

.third-section-paragraphs {
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -44px;
}

.plus-sign {
  color: #e7af17;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  .first-section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url("/assets/images/first-logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .small-button {
    width: 331px;
    height: 92px;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    background-color: #e7af17;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    border: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 940px) {
  .small-button {
    width: 331px;
    height: 92px;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    background-color: #e7af17;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    border: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1264px) {
  .first-section-p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .small-button {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 1%;
  }
  .footer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .info-box {
    margin-right: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 809px) {
  .first-section-p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .small-button {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 1%;
  }
  .second-section-right-part {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .footer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .first-section-p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .small-button {
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 1%;
  }
  .second-section-right-part {
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  .footer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">


  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="headers">
      <div class="nav">
        <a class="nav-h1"></a>
        <a href="" class="logo"></a>
        <div class="a-container">
          <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="/pages/about.html">About</a>
          <a href="/pages/solutions.html">Solutions</a>
          <a href="/pages/team.html">Team</a>
          <a href="/pages/contact.html">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="logo-section">
          <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook logo">
          <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin logo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-inside">
        <div class="first-section">
          <p class="first-section-p">Turnkey platforms <br> for businesses looking to rule the online market
            <button class="small-button">LEARN MORE</button>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="second-section">
          <div class="second-section-right-part">
            <div class="second-section-paragraphs">
              <p class="second-section-text">WHAT</p>
              <p class="second-section-text">WHE DO</p>
              <p class="second-section-text">BEST</p>
            </div>
            <section class="second-section-right-part">
              <div>
                <h3 class="second-section-right-part-h3"><span class="plus-sign">+</span> Media</h3>
                <p class="second-section-right-part-p">Social Media Offering a 360 degree solution to generating exposure via Social Media Marketing. Using both ATL and BTL strategies in large social networks such as Facebook and Linkedin but also in small networks when seeking a specific
                  demographic target.</p>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section class="second-section-right-part">
              <div>
                <h3 class="second-section-right-part-h3"> <span class="plus-sign">+</span>Sub-Affiliation</h3>
                <p class="second-section-right-part-p">Sub-Affiliation Genuinely strengthen your brand and jump start traffic with an affiliate program. Link with a large scale business led supply chain, monitor activity and generate returns through an exponentially growing platform.
                </p>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section class="second-section-right-part">
              <div>
                <h3 class="second-section-right-part-h3"> <span class="plus-sign">+</span>Mobile Adds
                </h3>
                <p class="second-section-right-part-p">Mobile Adds A multi-channeled platform tailor made for the mobile environment allowing ease of access, real time delivery and results driven optimization solutions allowing for cost efficient lead capture.
                </p>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third-section">
          <div class="third-section-left-part">
            <div class="third-section-paragraphs">
              <p class="third-section-text">ABOUT</p>
              <p class="third-section-text">US</p>
            </div>
            <h4 class="second-se">Leading The Way</h4>
            <br>
            <p class="third-section-left-part-p"> dynamic Online Media Powerhouse fueled with passion for developing and growing online businesses into world renowned enterprises. Putting a strong accent on online marketing solutions, Vici is one step ahead of the game with superior data
              management systems and prompt on key response time.
              <br><br> Streamlined by future oriented workflow methodology, Vici are a resilient group of focused and dedicated specialists that have a profound understanding of their duties and priorities.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="third-section-right-part">
            <section>
              <img src="/assets/images/people-laughing.png" alt="" class="third-section-right-part-img">
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="forth-section-paragraphs">
          <p class="forth-section-p">LET'S WORK TOGETHER?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="forth-section">
          <div class="info-box">
            <div class="info-box-content">
              <h1 class="info-box-content-h1">The Mission is Simple</h1>
              <p class="info-box-content-p">
                To Strategically Drive The Online Community Forward, Through A Wide Spectrum Integrating Market Intelligence And Experience Throughout, By Offering Unparalleled Resources And A True Understanding Of The Client’s Arena. </p>
              <br>
              <button>Contact Us &nbsp; >> </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="nav">
        <h5 class="nav-h1"></h5>
        <div class="a-container">
          <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="/pages/about.html">About</a>
          <a href="/pages/solutions.html">Solutions</a>
          <a href="/pages//team.html">Team</a>
          <a href="/pages/contact.html">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="logo-section">
          <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook logo">
          <img class="logo-img" src="/assets/images/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin logo">
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="message">*Please read the Privacy Policy and Terms & Conditions before continuing. <br> Use of our Services and Brokers websites is at your own risk. Information on our Website, applications and any marketing or email marketing material is strictly for information
        purposes and should not be construed as professional advice nor as an offer to engage in online trading, which may result in substantial or complete loss of funds.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: And it looks like, the site is already using 100% width.

Comment: Yes but the content does not stretch 100% as we see in the pictures

Answer (score -1):

To stretch your content use **Viewport Units** like **vw** and **vh** instead of **%** or **px** for all elements because it will not only stretch your content to whole screen, it will also make it responsive so that it can be used on all screen resolutions.

It will surely solve your issue but if you face any problem comment it and I will try my best to solve it.

Comment: @user13900804 **vh** is added in height and **vw** is added in width. And you have to try different  values of **vh** and **vw** to make it look the way you want. For reference, **1vw=0.5cm**. And i would recommend you to change values of all elements in **Viewport Units**. Try doing this and if it doesn't work, First, update your code in **Viewport Units** get back to me. And if it works please let me know.

Comment: I added 100vw to the width, but now the same issue showed on the desktop. It takes 100% on mobile devices, but 50% on the desktop view – user13900804

Comment: @user13900804 Can you please provide your code in **Viewport Units** to help me assist you better.

Comment: @user13900804  Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether your issue was solved or not?

Answer (score -2):

I just inspected your code and the reason it's not taking full width it because you have some text there (for example: "LET'S WORK TOGETHER") which has a `font-size` of `120px` in a container that has a `width` of only `45%`. Reduce the `font-size` and increase the `width` you will see how it will take full width.

add this to see the differnce:

```
.third-section-text, .forth-section-p {
   font-size:60px;
}

.forth-section-paragraphs {
   width:60%;
}
```

[image]

See how the `font-size` is making you the problem is dose not fit in the space it has. You will realize as you expand the window size that the issue is going away once the screen has enough room to put your content in the 45% width.

Comment: It works for mobile devices, but this way it cuts the page to 50% on the desktop view.

Comment: Your problem as I saw is only on smaller screen sizes. you can add @media queries to set individual css properties for each screen size

Comment: It would be better to find the issue that is causing the page to not stretch fully

Comment: The page is stretching fully on desktops your problem is on smaller screens only. And the reason is because of the font size

Comment: It is not the font sizes

Comment: there are many problems there with the website structure, but the issue with body not stretching is definitely the font-size. there is no way you can leave 120px on smaller screens without it overlapping

Comment: What other problems do you see? They are supposed to overlap. The problem is that the entire page content takes 50% of the window

Comment: Add this to the bottom of your css:

`@media (max-width: 1024px){
 .third-section-text, 
        .forth-section-p,
        .second-section-text {
               font-size:50px;
         }
        .second-section-right-part {
              margin-left:auto;
        }
       .first-section-p {
             margin:0 auto;
       }
       .forth-section-paragraphs,
.second-section-right-part,
.third-section-left-part{
   width:100%;
}
}`

I cannot fix it all as you should be able to do it on your own or hire a developer but with this alone you solve a lot of problems